# People smart collections - similar names problem

Tags: lightroom, keywords, smart-collections

I run a complete library of all my photos (100k+) and have quite a lot of smart collections.

The big problem I have is when tagging people

Ie the three **different** people:

- John Doe
- John Irvin Doe
- John Joseph Doe

How can I make indivudual smart collections for these?

```
I now have it set up like this:
Smart collection: John Doe
Keywords contain words John Doe

Smart collection: John Irvin Doe
Keywords contain words John Irvin Doe

Smart collection: John Joseph Doe
Keywords contain words John Joseph Doe
```

This works fine for Irvin and Joseph, but "John Doe" will then work as a container matching **all** of them.

I can't use any excludes as the similar names are usually family and might appear in the same photos.

Answer (score 4):

Your example is in fact worse than you realize: the rule `keywords contain words John Doe` will find photos with the keyword John Irvin Doe, John Joseph Doe, John Doe, as well as partial matches like Jane Doe and John Smith.

The trick is quotes: a filter with the rule `keywords contain words "John Doe"` will find only the keyword "John Doe."

Comment: Yeah I thought this would make sense, so I've already tried it. contains words "John Doe" gives me 0 photos, even though the keyword list to the right of it say I have 370 photos with that keyword. I've tried with multiple names as well, just in case. LR 5.5

Comment: Perhaps recheck that the keyword actually matches the filter. (Maybe the space is non-breaking or something?) I'm using this technique for a few Smart Collections for this very purpose, also with LR 5.5.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I've tried copy pasting the keyword text and also removing the keyword from the images and readding. If I add contain words and quotes around the keyword to any of my smart collections it fails to match any photos. Seems like this just wont work for me.

Comment: I've also tried to create a new catalog (thinking maybe an upgraded catalog had some faults), but still no luck. Seems like I can't filter on keywords with quotes. Could you verify that you are using normal double quotes for this?

Comment: You might want to rename them to John Doe A, John Doe B, and John Doe C.

Comment: Also, if you have not used quotes here, it might be that the image is not tagged "John Doe" but instead "John", "Doe". Then the Filter for "John Doe" obv. won't match anything.

Comment: @AndyBlankertz I could, but feel more like a hack than a fix. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Cornelius Hm, changing the tags to use quotes and the smart collection filter to use quotes works if I change from contain words to contain or contains all. Seems like this might work. Will try some more and see if this is it! Thanks!

Comment: @Cornelius Nope, doesn't seem to work the way I want. With contains all it matches "John and Doe". If I try to use contain words with the apostrophes then I get no matches at all :\

Comment: Ah I am sorry to hear :( I don't have lightroom, so I can't really test/help much. Fingers crossed that someone "in the know" stops by soon. :)

Comment: @Cornelius Thanks, but I think the answer is correct, must be something wrong with my setup

Comment: @JimL, for what it's worth I just rechecked and retested my Smart Collection filter. It is as I wrote, using "contains" (not "contains all" or any of the others), and this is the only rule in effect for that collection.